# Google Content Experiment doesn't show conversions for analytics.js

Tags: google-analytics

I created two landing pages.  I created a goal page and set up appropriate goal (type: Destination) in Google Analytics. I established a content experiment. There I specified two recently created landing pages as variations and my goal as objective.  Then I used 6 profiles of Google Chrome to perform a conversions. 
I called "Ctrl-Chift-Del" in each profile to completely remove all information for the beginning of time - just in case, to be sure that GA sessions will be created from scratch.

I visited A page from each profile. 3 of 6 visits has been redirected to B page. 
Then I consistently performed conversion (visited goal page) from each profile.

After several hours I got results. Experiment said me that there are 3 sessions for A variation and 3 sessions for B variation and there are no conversions.
Checked Content report: there are 3 hits of each A and B pages. Checked Conversions report: there are 6 hits of my goal. Double-checked settings of experiment: this goal is specified as objective. The problem is - no one conversion recorded by the experiment although 6 sessions started.

This problem is being reproduced only with **analytics.js** code, not with ga.js. I performed exactly same scenario but changed tracking code from analytics.js to **ga.js**. I successfully got 6 sessions and 6 conversions after several hours of experiment. Then I changed tracking code back to **analytics.js** - again, there are hits of A and B pages, there are hits of goal, there are 6 sessions but no conversion in experiment.

Comment: Just to check - did you leave it 1 day? Reports are only logged and associated in Analytics the next calendar day.

Comment: I've established new experiment and will wait 1 day.
But sessions are appeared in 3 hours. And both sessions and conversions  appeared in 3 hours when I using old tracking code.

Comment: New experiment brought sessions and no conversions. Is it worth to wait conversions if sessions are already present?

Comment: I waited more that 1 day. Still 6 sessions and no one converted... Sessions appeared very quickly (after 3 hours) but they did not "became converted" yet. I assume that they won't.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: No, I still use ga.js

Comment: Since I don't see any other comments about that and no other similar topics - it seems to me that problem is somehow connected with my account...